# Get inventory balance per year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm starting to learn SQL Server, and would like to ask for ideas on this problem. I have an inventory system, which has the following tables:

1. `Delivery Table (Stock_ID, Stock_Name, Quantity, Delivery_Date)`
2. `Disposal (Stock_ID, Stock_Name, Quantity, Disposal_Date)`

Sample `Delivery` Table:

```
Stock_ID    Stock_Name  Quantity    Delivery_Date
0001        Plates      500         6/6/2015
0002        Glasses     1000        6/7/2015
0003        Plates      800         9/8/2016
0004        Spoon       200         9/8/2016
0005        Glasses     300         9/8/2016
0006        Plates      1000        10/1/2017
0007        Spoon       800         10/1/2017
0008        Glasses     200         10/1/2017
```

Sample `Disposal` Table:

```
Stock_ID    Stock_Name  Quantity    Delivery_Date
0001        Plates      20          9/6/2015
0002        Glasses     100         10/7/2015
0003        Plates      30          10/8/2016
0004        Spoon       20          12/8/2016
0005        Glasses     10          12/8/2016
0006        Plates      100         12/1/2017
0007        Spoon       20          12/1/2017
0008        Glasses     20          12/1/2017
```

Basically, I want to get the delivery and disposal summaries per year, and the year-end balance of all the stocks.

Result table hopefully would look like:

```
 Stock_Name: Plates
                             2015           2016          2017
 1. Beginning Balance         0             480           1250
 2. Delivery                  500           800           1000
 3. Disposal                  20             30            100
 4. Balance                   480           1250          2150
```

I'm trying `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`, but I can't seem to get a grasp on how to make it work. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: show us what have you try? because should be a simple [**PIVOT.**](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky bit is doing the balance magic. This still requires hard coding of the years, you could use dynamic sql to build the query to have it work for arbitrary dates. There might be a simpler way to do this but this works:

```
create table Delivery (Stock_ID int, Stock_Name varchar(50), Quantity int, Delivery_Date date);
create table Disposal (Stock_ID int, Stock_Name varchar(50), Quantity int, Disposal_Date date);

insert into delivery values(0001, 'Plates' , 500  , '6/6/2015');
insert into delivery values(0002, 'Glasses', 1000 , '6/7/2015');
insert into delivery values(0003, 'Plates' , 800  , '9/8/2016');
insert into delivery values(0004, 'Spoon'  , 200  , '9/8/2016');
insert into delivery values(0005, 'Glasses', 300  , '9/8/2016');
insert into delivery values(0006, 'Plates' , 1000 , '10/1/2017');
insert into delivery values(0007, 'Spoon'  , 800  , '10/1/2017');
insert into delivery values(0008, 'Glasses', 200  , '10/1/2017');


insert into disposal values(0001, 'Plates' ,  20 , '9/6/2015');
insert into disposal values(0002, 'Glasses',  100, '10/7/2015');
insert into disposal values(0003, 'Plates' ,  30 , '10/8/2016');
insert into disposal values(0004, 'Spoon'  ,  20 , '12/8/2016');
insert into disposal values(0005, 'Glasses',  10 , '12/8/2016');
insert into disposal values(0006, 'Plates' ,  100, '12/1/2017');
insert into disposal values(0007, 'Spoon'  ,  20 , '12/1/2017');
insert into disposal values(0008, 'Glasses',  20 , '12/1/2017');

declare @stock varchar(50);
set @stock = 'Plates';

with transactions as
(
    select Quantity, 
        Delivery_Date as D 
    from Delivery 
    where Stock_Name = @stock
    union 
    select -Quantity, 
        Disposal_Date as D 
    from Disposal 
    where Stock_Name = @stock
),
ordered as 
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by D) rn
    from transactions
),
running as
(
    select *, sum(Quantity) over (order by rn rows unbounded preceding) running
    from ordered
),
ordered2 as
(
    select year(D) Y, 
        running as val, 
        row_number() over (partition by year(D) order by D) rnasc,
        row_number() over (partition by year(D) order by D desc) rndesc
    from running
),
data1 as 
(
    select 1 as ord, 'Beginning Balance' as row, o2.Y, isnull(b.val,0) as val
    from ordered2 o2
    outer apply (
        select val from ordered2 i2 where i2.Y = o2.Y - 1 and rndesc =1 
    ) b
    where rnasc = 1
),
data2 as
(
    select 2 as ord, 'Delivery' as row, year(Delivery_Date) as Y, sum(Quantity) as Quantity from Delivery where Stock_Name = @stock
    group by year(Delivery_Date)
),
data3 as 
(
    select 3 as ord, 'Disposal' as row, year(Disposal_Date) as Y, sum(Quantity) as Quantity from Disposal where Stock_Name = @stock
    group by year(Disposal_Date)
),
data4 as
(
    select 4 as ord, 'Balance' as row, o2.Y, val
    from ordered2 o2
    where rndesc = 1
),
data as 
(
    select * from data1
    union select * from data2
    union select * from data3
    union select * from data4
)
select row, [2015], [2016], [2017]
from 
(   
    select ord, row, y, val
    from data
) as s
pivot 
(
    sum(val)
    for y IN ([2015],[2016],[2017])
) as p
order by ord
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just tweaked a little, but almost everything fit exactly how I want it. Learned a lot from this. Now I'm studying how to do the dynamic sql for the YEAR part, but this has been a great help. Thank you so much! :)